# Android emulator can not start in Ubuntu-12.04-64bit ("X Error of failed request: BadRequest")

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, android-emulator

Starting emulator for AVD '4.12'
  X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  136 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  14 (X_GLXGetVisualConfigs)
  Serial number of failed request:  12
  Current serial number in output stream:  12

And I have already install the driver of NVI.So I want to know the reason of it.Thanks a lot!

Comment: same here: ubuntu 13.04  Starting emulator for AVD 't1'
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 (ATIFGLEXTENSION)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  66 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  13
  Current serial number in output stream:  13